# JQuery Mobile Dialog Not Opening

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am following Sams teach yourself jquery mobile in 24 hours. But following code is not working.

I tried to debug javascript but there is no javascript. And if there is a way to debug jquery mobile that would be nice.
    
    
    
        Isuru's Résumé

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Isuru's R&#233;sum&#233;</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>I'm a Mobile Developer with experience in web and android mobile app development. 
                My skills include HTML, CSS, Python, WAMP Development and Java. 
                I also have experience with SEO and Internet Advertising.</p>
            <a href="#contact" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Contact me!</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="contact" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="header"><h1>Clicked!</h1></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Clicked content!</p>
                <a href="#contact" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few errors.

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Isuru's R&#233;sum&#233;</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>I'm a Mobile Developer with experience in web and android mobile app development. 
                My skills include HTML, CSS, Python, WAMP Development and Java. 
                I also have experience with SEO and Internet Advertising.</p>
            <a href="#contact" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Contact me!</a>
        </div>
    </div>   

  <div data-role="dialog" id="contact" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Clicked!</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Clicked content!</p>
      <a href="#contact" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
    </div>
  </div>   

</body>
</html>
```

And here's jsFiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/w3ptm/

You had this errors:

1. In dialog **data-role="page"** must be a **data-role="dialog"**

   ```
   <div data-role="dialog" id="contact" data-theme="c">
       <div data-role="header"><h1>Clicked!</h1></div>
       <div data-role="content">
           <p>Clicked content!</p>
           <a href="#contact" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. It also must be on the same level as main page.